# Syntax high-lighting a CUDA (.cu) program in visual studio (2005 and/or 2008)

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, gpgpu

I'm new to GPU-programming with CUDA and have just installed everyting on my machine to get started, and it's working. Big victory! However, when I open the code samples in VS(2005 and 2008) NVidia provides the cuda-program (.cu) files are just black and white. This is expected, but I wonder if there is any way to bring a bit more color into the program? I can recall reading about this somewhere in some release notes or the like, but now when I really want to see what it said I can't find the text.

Is there any way of high-lighting syntax in CUDA-programs and in such a case how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a link describing how to do that:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120712154231/http://codereflect.com/2008/09/04/how-to-enable-syntax-highlighting-for-cuda-files-in-visual-studio-2005/